# How to cope with older library installed in `/usr/lib` by sysadmin

Tags: c++, c, ld

I have recently got an account on a supercomputer grid, and I'm trying to compile my code in theri system. Problem is that program won't link with following errors:

```
/mnt/opt/tools/slc6/binutils/2.22/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.55.0, needed by /mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55//lib/libboost_thread.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.5
/mnt/opt/tools/slc6/binutils/2.22/bin/ld: /mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55//lib/libboost_thread.so: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/mnt/opt/tools/slc6/binutils/2.22/bin/ld: note: '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv' is defined in DSO /mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55//lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55//lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which is due to the fact that my program needs boost 1.55, and only 1.39 is instlled on the system in `/usr/lib64`. I have installed my version of boost in local folder, but somehow still system one is loaded first.

Here is excerpt from flags passed to the compiler:

```
  -std=gnu++11 -Werror -Wall -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_iostreams -g -DG4OPTIMISE -Iinclude 
  -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-long-long -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Woverloaded-virtual -pipe -O2
```

full [listing of flags is here](http://pastebin.com/VVRs3Cke) (they should be irrevelant).

Here are revelant config variables:

```
 LIBRARY_PATH /mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55/lib: 
 CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH /mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55/include:/mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/geant4.9.6.3/compile/include/Geant4
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH /mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55/lib:/mnt/opt/tools/slc6/gcc/4.8.3/lib64: ...
```

Directory `/mnt/home/jbzdak/tools/boost_1_55` contains installed boost library.

I use `GCC` 4.8.3 with `ld` 2.22.

I have very little experience with linker errors hence the question. Is there any way to exclude boost libraries in /usr/lib64, or make the linker use locally installed libraries, and and ignore the system one?

Comment: The `.../libboost_system.so.1.55.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation` is weird. Can you check if you have this file corrupted or something?

Comment: I checked it with ``file``, and it said that its a: ``libboost_system.so.1.55.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped``. So it looks OK, at least on the surface. 

Is there any way to check whether a dynamic lib is not corrupted?

Comment: To people trying to close this: this is not about general computing tools, or server administration, but about **compilation** process thats on topic on SO.

Comment: There's no `-L/alternative/location/of/boost/lib` shown, so the compiler (linker) doesn't know it needs to look somewhere else for your modern Boost library.  You may need `-Wl,rpath,/alternative/location/of/boost/lib` as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler adding `-L` solved my issue. If you'll submit this as an answer I'll accept it (it would be great if you explained why didint ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` solved the issue :)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I said in a comment:

> There's no `-L/alternative/location/of/boost/lib` shown, so the compiler (linker) doesn't know it needs to look somewhere else for your modern Boost library. You may need `-Wl,rpath,/alternative/location/of/boost/lib` as well.

And the question was asked:

> Why didn't `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solve the issue?

Because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a run-time variable rather than a link-time variable.  It affects where the `/lib/ld.so.1` (or equivalent) dynamic loader looks for libraries when you run a program, not where the linker looks to find its libraries.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional debugging and asking [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136948), I found out the root cause of problem. Any `-L` parameter has precedence over `LIBRARY_PATH` and somehow `-L/usr/lib64` was added (hence it had precedence over my version).

To check what options are sent to `gcc` pass `-v` parameter.